deck.gl error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: VERSION is not defined"
I want to create an app using Deck.gl to render a map to take advantage of WebGL for rendering vector tiles. I have a .mbtiles file served using Tileserver-GL. It works using OpenLayers, but I would like to try with Deck.gl as well. After following instructions from the docs, I keep getting this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: VERSION is not defined" referencing deck.js:99 and am struggling to fix it. Here is my map component:
import React from 'react';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {MVTLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';

const DeckGLMap = () => {
  const layer = new MVTLayer({
    id: 'mvtlayer',
    data: [
      'tileserver-gl-url'
    ],
    minZoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 13
  })

  return (
    <DeckGL
      initialViewState={{
        longitude: -87,
        latitude: 36
      }}
      layers={[layer]}
    />
  )
}

export default DeckGLMap

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the dependencies multiple times but it still refuses to render anything. I am wondering if this could be some sort of webpack error. Does anyone have experience with this error or similar ones?
